# In which context is "lignicolous" used?

Tags: meaning, terminology, biology

Is *lignicolous* a word used in a specific context, or is it common to say "that is a lignicolous bug"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* doesn't have any match for it, nor does the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, so it's not that common.

It means [“that lives in or on wood or wood debris”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lignicolous). It is mostly used in academic or scientific writing, so you mean learn more about its usage from the [Google Scholar search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=lignicolous&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=on). Apparently, **it is mainly applied to fungi**, as in “lignicolous fungi of the forests of New Hampshire”.

Answer (score 1):

As an adjective, [lignicolous](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/lignicolous) is appropriate to describe anything growing or living on or in wood. However, I would suggest considering whether your audience has experience with that word, or handy access to a dictionary.

You could just as easily say "That bug lives in wood."